# Encryption in WebSocket

Tags: encryption, websocket

I'm creating a software that serves as a WebSocket server to a web application. It serves to basically backup and store important files generated in the web. Some of these files are sensitive and private to the company using the software.

I imagine something like this:
[image: Encryption/Decryption example]

The message would be a file in String format, and Alice's key would have be the same both in the Web application and in the Desktop application, shared somehow.

My first thought would be to encrypt those files when they're sent and decrypt them on the server. Although, how can I keep consistency of the key used to decrypt it? It doesn't seem safe to share the key via WebSocket so both server and client have the same key. So that's a question in a safety standpoint, what is the best/correct approach to that? Also, do you have any recommendations on encryption/decription libraries for Java and JavaScript that would be compatible?

Comment: What's wrong with simply using standard SSL/TLS encryption?  A WebSocket starts life as an HTTP connection.  If that connection uses HTTPS via a `wss://` url instead of a `ws://` url, the WebSocket will be encrypted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the standard SSL/TSL encryption is safe enough, so that someone listening the connection from outside would not be able to decipher the messages?

Comment: Yes.  That is the whole point of SSL/TLS. The majority of the WWW in general depends on that guarantee for its security.

Comment: Awesome, I was trying to reinvent the wheel here then, thanks for the clarification!